# python - NameError global name 'buf' is not defined

Tags: python

I don't know what this error means. Any advice about the error or the rest of the code is greatly appreciated.

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import os
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def image_scrape():
    url = raw_input("Type url for image scrape: ")
    content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
    name = 0
    for tag in soup.find_all(re.compile("img")):
        path = 'C:\Users\Sorcerer\Downloads'
        name += 1
        filename = name
        file_path = "%s%s" % (path, filename)
        downloaded_image = file(file_path, "wb")
        downloaded_image.write(buf)
        downloaded_image.close()

image_scrape()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a line in your code:

```
downloaded_image.write(buf)
```

The Python interpreter has not seen this variable `buf` before in your code. And hence the error.

Thoughts on the rest of your code:

- It is advisable to use the `os` module to do what you are doing with this line:

  ```
  file_path = "%s%s" % (path, filename)
  ```

  like this:

  ```
  import os
  path = os.path.normpath('C:\\Users\\Sorcerer\\Downloads')
  file_path = os.path.join(path, name)
  ```
- Looks like you are trying to find all the image links in the page and trying to save it to the file system at the location referenced by `file_path`. Assuming the link to the image is in the variable `tag`, this is what you do:

  ```
  import requests
  r = requests.get(tag, stream=True)
  if r.status_code == 200:
      with open(name, 'wb') as f:
          for chunk in r.iter_content():
              f.write(chunk)
      f.close()
  ```

Comment: so how do I define buf and if I don't need it what should I put because .write() requires at least 1 argument? ps thanks for the help

Comment: also now I'm getting this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sorcerer\programs\img_scrape.py", line 20, in <module>
    image_scrape()
  File "C:\Users\Sorcerer\programs\img_scrape.py", line 15, in image_scrape
    file_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 73, in join
    elif isabs(b):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 57, in isabs
    s = splitdrive(s)[1]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 125, in splitdrive
    if p[1:2] == ':':
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: @torchhound Updated the answer. Look at the `normpath` usage